# How to query date values from sql using python where I only have the year and month

Tags: python, sqlite, date, where-clause, sql-like

I have these records in my database:

[image]

and I want to select them using python, however I only have the year and month which is stored in a variable:

[image: variable]

Here is my code: [image: code]

However this does not work, and I've only gotten it to work when using a fully specific date, e.g. 2022-06-11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the column Date in the table are strings in the proper format `yyyy-MM-dd` and you can use the operator `LIKE`:

```
c.execute("SELECT Category, Amount FROM transactions WHERE Date LIKE ? || '%'", (month_selected,))
```

or, with the function [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
c.execute("SELECT Category, Amount FROM transactions WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = ?", (month_selected,))
```